How can i stop increasing the box of UL tag
I am trying to create a TODO list app on web but there is a problem that makes me drain. The problem is that when I add the task it shows below in a box of UL tag, the task shows well when the text is short, but when the text inside the box is long the box increases itself according to the text. That makes my whole webpage design worst.
Then I fixed it by setting the  width to a fixed size but know the text is cut, the full text is not showing.
This is my code :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="todo_app.css">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200&icon_names=delete" />
</head>
<body>
   <div class="box">
    <h1 id="heading">TO-DO APP</h1>
    <div id="input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="enter the task" id="inp">
        <button id="btn" onclick="add()">ADD</button>
        <div id="txt"></div>
        <script src="todo_app.js"></script>
    </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html> 

JAVASCRIPT:
let input=document.getElementById("inp");
let text=document.querySelector("#txt");
function add()
{
    if(input.value=="")
    {
        alert("please enter the task");
    }
    else
    {
        let newele=document.createElement("ul");
        newele.innerHTML =`${input.value}<i class="material-symbols-outlined">delete</i>`;
        text.appendChild(newele);
        input.value="";

    }
}


CSS: overflow: hidden; should be the first thing you try.

Try: overflow:auto which will auto add a scroll bar rather than cut-off your text

Potentially off topic: You're creating a ul then putting text/icon inside that ul - but without a li.  This is incorrect/invalid HTML and may not be rendered by the browser as you're expecting it, which may affect your layout. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul#technical_summary Permitted content

Please update the question to include a [mcve] as a runnable code snippet which demonstrates the problem you are trying to describe.  You've tagged CSS and appear to be describing a styling problem, but have included no CSS code.

FYI: SO uses a "tag" system to help people find questions that they are interested in.   There's no need to add extra tags.  Each tag has a description which is shown when you select it and can be clicked to get more info.  Under the [tag:todo] it states "Please do not use this for questions about creating todo list applications."
